# Adding rows to the Google Data Visualization Table

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to add different set of lat,long in the google visualization table by iterating over the Ajax get response, it looks like only the last value in the response json is added to the row,

Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '/api/v1.0/tasks/'+document.getElementById("autocomplete").value,
          dataType: 'json',
          data: { 'value' : $(this).val() },
          success : function(data){

          for(var i=0; i<data.task.length; i++) {

             var lat,long,name;
             var lat = data.task[i].lat
             var longi = data.task[i].longi
              var name = data.task[i].markerText
             alert(lat,longi,name)
             var datag = new google.visualization.DataTable();
              datag.addColumn('number', 'lat');
              datag.addColumn('number', 'longi');
               datag.addColumn('string', 'markerstr');
               datag.addRows([[lat,longi,name],]);
        }

})
```

Expected Output:

```
data = [[37.6153, -122.3900, 'Airport'],
                                     [37.4422, -122.1731, 'Shopping'],]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are rebuilding the data structure each time you iterate. It happens that your headers are the same. But in this case the whole data gets re-written on each iteration. Perhaps try something like this.

```
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/api/v1.0/tasks/'+document.getElementById("autocomplete").value,
      dataType: 'json',
      data: { 'value' : $(this).val() },
      success : function(data){


      var datag = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          datag.addColumn('number', 'lat');
          datag.addColumn('number', 'longi');
          datag.addColumn('string', 'markerstr');
      var rows = []
      for(var i=0; i<data.task.length; i++) {

         var lat,long,name;
         var lat = data.task[i].lat
         var longi = data.task[i].longi
         var name = data.task[i].markerText
         rows.push([lat,longi,name]);
    }
      datag.addRows(rows);
 })
```

Comment: Yeah that's a mistake but it doesn't fix the issue, I can still see only the last marker on the map

Comment: Erm.. Which means that the addRows array needs to be totally build first and then added once at the end, maybe. I updated the code again.